# jQuery datepicker prev and next buttons not showing, how to point at theme folder images in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have used the jQuery ui datepicker to successfully add a calendar control to my textbox, but the previous and next buttons are not visible although the containing tag works functionally when clicking

The  how can I modify this to show the icons shown on the http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ when these images are found within my web package at ..\Content\theme\base\images and not the locations shown below

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
```

Do I need to call the image within css in a similar fashion to how images are called from within my c# code? As in:

```
"@Url.Content("~/Content/theme/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png")"
```

Comment: Please post your code here. A link to the working demo at jqueryui.com doesn't give us any idea why your code isn't working.

Comment: edited with more detail

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make sure your `jquery-ui.min.css` is pointing to the correct file for the images. The console should show an error when you are attempting to load the icons.

For example, If this is the location of your CSS file: `http://example.com/css/jquery-ui.min.css`, then the icon file should be in `http://example.com/css/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png`. The link in the CSS file is relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file loading it.

Comment: I have edited the original post with more detail. How do I point to the correct image which I have with ~Content/theme/base/images

Comment: Thank you! I made the same mistake!

Comment: create a folder called images inside the folder of your css and include the images of icons found here: http://www.corebiz.com.br/clientes/new_boti/assets/images/jquery-ui-dist/images/

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there.

Just ensure you change your url and add the "!important" at the end of the line.

This will allow you to add any image you wish.

```
    .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("../../images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png")      
    !important;}
    .ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("../../images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png")   
    !important;}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are mission `ui-icons_444444_256x240.png` image. You can Download that image from here [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/themes/base/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png).

Now create a folder named - `images` and add that folder image inside that folder.

Example

```
http://example.com/css/jquery-ui.min.css
http://example.com/css/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I tried changing the relative urls in the jquery-ui files but the images still weren't showing.  Instead I had to put the directives in my site.css file.  My files are loaded by the BundleConfig.cs file.

I put relative path in my site.css file and the images started work.

```css
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("../../Scripts/lib/jquery-ui/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from the error message that the site was looking in:

`http://site/Content/images/image.png`

I'm not quite sure why, as from Mooseman's answer:

> The link in the CSS file is relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file loading it.

It seems that the link was relative from `site.css` (which is contained in `Content`) rather than `Jquery-ui.mincss`, and so it obviously could not find the png.

After changing the paths in `JQuery-ui.min.css` to

`themes/base/images/image.png`

It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the most simple answer,

1. Go to the site [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/) and download the file with default settings.
2. Extract the file.
3. Copy the "images" folder and put it in you project in the same folder where the jQuery ui css resides and that will take care the problem.

Credits to [Gullele's Corner](https://gullele.com/date-picker-in-jquery-misses-next-and-prev-arrow-how-to-add-arrow-on-jquery-date-picker/#comment-30445), I just simply updated the procedure since the folder structure change (May 2019).